# How to increase points when a rect collides with another rect and the left mouse button is clicked?

Tags: python, pygame

So I am making a game where the player has to click  on a moving rect (a tennis ball) to get points. So far I have created the tennis ball and some other balls, and I have got them moving randomly round the screen and bouncing off the edges. I have also made a rect called target which moves with the mouse. I would like the game to add 10 points every time the player clicks on the tennis ball (with the target) and deduct a life if they click elsewhere on the screen. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks :)

```
import pygame
import sys

from random import *
from pygame.locals import *


#game        
pygame.init()
running=True
screen_width=800
screen_height=600
screen=pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width,screen_height])
background_colour = (0,0,150)
screen.fill(background_colour)

clock=pygame.time.Clock()
game_sound='pumpup.wav'
pygame.mixer.init()
points=0
lives=3

#balls
x= randint(20,40)
y= randint(20,40)
ball=pygame.image.load ('ball_t.png')
ball_movement=[x,y]#amount ball moves each time (x,y)
ball_location=[100,100]#x,y co-ordinates for start position
ball_rect=ball.get_rect()#gets rectangle for ball

x2= randint(5,15)
y2= randint(5,15)

ball2_movement=[x2,y2]#amount ball moves each time (x,y)
ball2_location=[10,10]#x,y co-ordinates for start position
ball2=pygame.image.load ('ball_tt.png')
ball2_rect=ball2.get_rect()#gets rectangle for ball

x3= randint(10,40)
y3= randint(10,30)

ball3_movement=[x3,y3]#amount ball moves each time (x,y)
ball3_location=[10,100]#x,y co-ordinates for start position
ball3=pygame.image.load ('ball_b.png')
ball3_rect=ball3.get_rect()#gets rectangle for ball

x4= randint(10,30)
y4= randint(10,30)

ball4_movement=[x4,y4]#amount ball moves each time (x,y)
ball4_location=[200,100]#x,y co-ordinates for start position
ball4=pygame.image.load ('ball_bs.png')
ball4_rect=ball4.get_rect()#gets rectangle for ball

#target
target_location=[200,100]#x,y co-ordinates for start position
target=pygame.image.load ('Target.png')
target_rect=target.get_rect()#gets rectangle for ball
target_rect.center=target_location

#score
font=pygame.font.Font(None, 50)#default font
score="Score: {}".format(points)
score_text=font.render(score,1,(0,200,250))
text_pos=[10,10] #position on screen

#lives
font=pygame.font.Font(None, 50)#default font
livest="Lives: {}".format(lives)
lives_text=font.render(livest,1,(0,200,250))
textl_pos=[650,10]#position on screen




#show initial screen
screen.blit(ball, ball_rect)#draws ball on its rectangle
screen.blit(ball2, ball2_rect)
screen.blit(ball3, ball3_rect)
screen.blit(ball4, ball4_rect)
screen.blit(target, target_rect)
screen.blit(score_text, text_pos)
screen.blit(lives_text, textl_pos)

pygame.display.flip() #displays screen


while running: #event loop
    clock.tick(50) #won't run at more than 60 frames per second
    screen.fill([0,0,150])#clears screen

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            running=False
        elif event.type==pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
        target_rect.centerx=event.pos[0] #moves target with mouse
        target_rect.centery=event.pos[1]
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and target_rect.colliderect(ball2_rect):
       points=100 




    if ball_rect.left<0 or ball_rect.right>screen_width: #check whether ball is off screen (x)
        ball_movement[0]=-ball_movement[0]#change direction on x axis
    if ball_rect.top<0 or ball_rect.bottom>screen_height: #check whether ball is off screen (y)
        ball_movement[1]=-ball_movement[1] #change direction on y axis

    if ball2_rect.left<0 or ball2_rect.right>screen_width: #check whether ball is off screen (x)
        ball2_movement[0]=-ball2_movement[0]#change direction on x axis
    if ball2_rect.top<0 or ball2_rect.bottom>screen_height: #check whether ball is off screen (y)
        ball2_movement[1]=-ball2_movement[1] #change direction on y axis

    if ball3_rect.left<0 or ball3_rect.right>screen_width: #check whether ball is off screen (x)
        ball3_movement[0]=-ball3_movement[0]
    if ball3_rect.top<0 or ball3_rect.bottom>screen_height: #check whether ball is off screen (y)
        ball3_movement[1]=-ball3_movement[1] #change direction on y axis

    if ball4_rect.left<0 or ball4_rect.right>screen_width: #check whether ball is off screen (x)
        ball4_movement[0]=-ball4_movement[0]
    if ball4_rect.top<0 or ball4_rect.bottom>screen_height: #check whether ball is off screen (y)
        ball4_movement[1]=-ball4_movement[1] #change direction on y axis



    if ball_rect.top > screen_height and lives >0:
        lives=lives-1
        livest="Lives: {}".format(lives)
        lives_text=font.render(livest,1,(0,0,0))
        pygame.time.delay(500)#pause
        ball_rect.topleft=[10,0] #reinstate ball
    if lives ==0:
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.delay(2500)#pause
        running=False





    ball_rect=ball_rect.move(ball_movement)#move ball
    ball2_rect=ball2_rect.move(ball2_movement)
    ball3_rect=ball3_rect.move(ball3_movement)
    ball4_rect=ball4_rect.move(ball4_movement)
    screen.blit(ball, ball_rect)#redraws ball
    screen.blit(ball2, ball2_rect)
    screen.blit(ball3, ball3_rect)
    screen.blit(ball4, ball4_rect)
    screen.blit(target, target_rect)
    screen.blit(score_text, text_pos)
    screen.blit(lives_text, textl_pos)


    pygame.display.flip() #displays screen

pygame.quit() #quits game
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend not creating a ball 4 different times. Instead, create a ball class and make 4 ball objects. Try this

```
class ball:
    def __init__(self, x, y, image, location):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.img = image
        self.movement = [x, y]
        self.rect = self.img.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = location
```

Then, you can get rid of all of this:

```
x= randint(20,40)
y= randint(20,40)
ball=pygame.image.load ('ball_t.png')
ball_movement=[x,y]#amount ball moves each time (x,y)
ball_location=[100,100]#x,y co-ordinates for start position
ball_rect=ball.get_rect()#gets rectangle for ball

x2= randint(5,15)... etc.
```

and replace it all with this:

```
balls = []
balls.append(ball(randint(20, 40), randint(20, 40), 'ball_t.png', [100, 100])
balls.append(ball(randint(5, 15), randint(5, 15), 'ball_tt.png', [10, 10])
balls.append(ball(randint(10, 40), randint(10, 30), 'ball_b.png', [10, 100])
balls.append(ball(randint(10, 30), randint(10, 30), 'ball_bs.png', [200, 100])
```

Then, take this part:

```
    if ball_rect.left<0 or ball_rect.right>screen_width: #check whether ball is off screen (x)
        ball_movement[0]=-ball_movement[0]#change direction on x axis
    if ball_rect.top<0 or ball_rect.bottom>screen_height: #check whether ball is off screen (y)
        ball_movement[1]=-ball_movement[1] #change direction on y axis

    if ball2... etc.
```

and replace it with a method of ball.

```
class ball:
    def __init__():
        blah blah blah init

    def is_touching_wall(self):
        if self.rect.left < 0 or self.rect.right > screen_width:
            self.movement[0] -= self.movement[0]
        if self.rect.top < 0 or self.rect.bottom > screen_height: 
            self.movement[1] -= self.movement[1]
```

and then in the main function:

```
for ball in balls:
    ball.is_touching_wall()
```

And then lastly, add one more method to the ball class:

```
def update(self):
    self.rect = self.rect.move(self.movement)
    screen.blit(self.img, self.rect)
```

and replace this part:

```
ball_rect=ball_rect.move(ball_movement)#move ball
ball2_rect=ball2_rect.move(ball2_movement)
ball3_rect=ball3_rect.move(ball3_movement)
ball4_rect=ball4_rect.move(ball4_movement)
screen.blit(ball, ball_rect)#redraws ball
screen.blit(ball2, ball2_rect)
screen.blit(ball3, ball3_rect)
screen.blit(ball4, ball4_rect)
```

with this:

```
for ball in balls:
    ball.update()
```

Lastly, two more recommendations.

1. Don't post questions on SE saying, "Here's my code. Fix it." You never specified what you tried to fix the problem, where in your code the problem is, or even exactly what your question was. Also, try to only post the smallest part of your code that will replicate your problem. Fix your code, and add more information to your question, and then people will be a lot more willing to help you with the target.
2. Pay attention to formatting. Read [PEP-8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Add spaces inbetween arguments and inbetween comparisons. Indent better. Import this. etc...